# Filling an array in a linkedList?

Tags: java

a student class for example

i had them in an array

how can i put the array into the linked list..??

Comment: There's a `delete` link below the question.

Comment: I think you mean; how do I add the elements of an array to a list? in that case; use a loop to add each element.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] array = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```